# Redis bitmap split key division strategy

Tags: redis, bitmap

I'm grabbing and archiving A LOT of data from the Federal Elections Commission public data source API which has a unique record identifier called "sub_id" that is a 19 digit integer.

I'd like to think of a memory efficient way to catalog which line items I've already archived and immediately redis bitmaps come to mind.

Reading the documentation on redis bitmaps indicates a maximum storage length of 2^32 (4294967296).

A 19 digit integer could theoretically range anywhere from 0000000000000000001 - 9999999999999999999. Now I know that the datasource in question does not actually have 99 quintillion records, so they are clearly sparsely populated and not sequential. Of the data I currently have on file the maximum ID is 4123120171499720404 and a minimum value of 1010320180036112531. (I can tell the ids a date based because the 2017 and 2018 in the keys correspond to the dates of the records they refer to, but I can't sus out the rest of the pattern.)

If I wanted to store which line items I've already downloaded would I need 2328306436 different redis bitmaps? (9999999999999999999 / 4294967296 = 2328306436.54). I could probably work up a tiny algorithm determine given an 19 digit idea to divide by some constant to determine which split bitmap index to check.

There is no way this strategy seems tenable so I'm thinking I must be fundamentally misunderstanding some aspect of this. Am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Bloom Filter such as **RedisBloom** will be an optimal solution (RedisBloom can even grow if you miscalculated your desired capacity).

After you BF.**CREATE** your filter, you pass to BF.**ADD** an 'item' to be inserted. This item can be as long as you want. The filter uses hash functions and modulus to fit it to the filter size. When you want to check if the item was already checked, call BF.**EXISTS** with the 'item'.

In short, what you describe here is a classic example for when a Bloom Filter is a great fit.

Answer (score 1):

How many "items" are there? What is "A LOT"?

Anyway. A linear approach that uses a single bit to track each of the 10^19 potential items requires 1250 petabytes at least. This makes it impractical (atm) to store it in memory.

I would recommend that you teach yourself about probabilistic data structures in general, and after having grokked the tradeoffs look into using something from the  [RedisBloom](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisbloom/) toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

If the ids ids are not sequential and very spread, keep tracking of which one you processed using a bitmap is not the best option since it would waste lot of memory.

However, it is hard to point the best solution without knowing the how many distinct `sub_id`s your data set has. If you are talking about a few 10s of millions, a simple set in Redis may be enough.